# Plugin for replacing text with HTML

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, parsing

I've written a jQuery Plugin which searches text and replaces it with other text or HTML.

Now everything works quite well, but recently I came across this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962406/style-all-letters-on-any-webpage#comment55710443_33962406) where the OP could have use of my plugin. That's why I linked to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/toesslab/jQueryReplaceMe) and asked him for critiques and/or contribution.

Soon after, he said that my plugin would have slow down his page by the factor 17 (I don't think this number is coming from the dev console though). Anyway, that comment made me think about how to make my plugin faster.

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.replaceMe = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            textToReplace: 'any_text',
            replaceWithText: '<span>othertext</span>',
            globally: true,
            excludedTags: [
                'img',
                'span'
            ]
        }, options);
        $(this).contents().each(function (index, node) {
            var text,
                excludedTags;
            if(node.innerHTML !== undefined) {
                text = node.innerHTML;
            } else {
                text = node.nodeValue;
            }
            excludedTags = (node.localName === null || node.localName === undefined) ? '' : node.localName;
            if (text.match(new RegExp(settings.textToReplace, 'g')) && node.nodeType === 3 && !excludedTags.match(new RegExp(settings.excludedTags.join('|')))) {
                if(settings.globally) {
                    $(node).replaceWith(text.replace(new RegExp(settings.textToReplace, 'g'), settings.replaceWithText));
                } else {
                    $(node).replaceWith(text.replace(new RegExp(settings.textToReplace), settings.replaceWithText));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

On the testing environment, the text to parse counts **169,310** chars or **27,391** words.

The Chrome console says that the script needs **42 ms** to perform. Now I'm not sure if the script needs any improvement and if yes what could be done to make it faster.

Comment: I would think a time complexity issue would come from the usage of Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that a major time complexity comes from the usage of Regex which involves 'steps' in the processing of the expression, meaning the complex the statement, the more steps it can take.

Instead of using a Regex for when `settings.globally` is false, a normal `String.replace` can be done.

And instead of using a Regex for the global checks, I would suggest using a `String.prototype.replaceAll` polyfill like the following:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace){
    var string = this;
    var index = 0;
    while ((index = string.indexOf(search)) !== -1) {
        string = string.replace(search, replace);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Which would change the `settings.globally` block into:

```
if(settings.globally) {
    $(node).replaceWith(text.replaceAll(settings.textToReplace, settings.replaceWithText));
} else {
    $(node).replaceWith(text.replace(settings.textToReplace, settings.replaceWithText));
}
```

I would also suggest removing jQuery from the solution as well. `extend`, `$` (the element fetching), `match` and `each` can be polyfilled in, or simply converted to vanilla JavaScript.

```
function $(selector, el) {
    if (!el) { el = document; }
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
}
var extend = function(out) {
  out = out || {};
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (!arguments[i])
      continue;
    for (var key in arguments[i]) {
      if (arguments[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
        out[key] = arguments[i][key];
    }
  }
  return out;
};
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function() {'use strict';
    return String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this, arguments) !== -1;
  };
}
```

and for `each`: you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (The polyfill is quite large, so I didn't include it) or a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll test that out. I don't understand the last part of your answer ***"removing jQuery from the solution as well. extend, $ (the element fetching), match and each can be polyfilled in, or simply converted to vanilla JavaScript"***. Could you eventually explain that or link to some docs?

Comment: Daenu, I've added polyfills for the referenced functions

Comment: Now I got it. Seems that I've to update my JS skills ;-)